# Call function from another function Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to call a function from another function as below, but it is throwing an error as mentioned below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `all_function`(runInstance double) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
CALL al_compareData(runInstance);

RETURN 1;
END
```

error thrown is

```
Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE als.al_compareData does not exist
```

I am trying to call a function, but MySQL in turn is searching for a procedure.

How to call a function from another function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you omit `CALL` and just use `al_compareData(runInstance);`

`CALL` is meant to be used with procedures only. What the function returns is meant to be used/assigned in your block. Also, if you try

```
SELECT al_compareData(runInstance);
```

outside your procedure, it will return the result, just for you to know.

Maybe you want to use the value returned, so you could do something like

```
SET compareResult = al_compareData(runInstance);
IF (compareResult) THEN
    --something
ELSE
    --something else
END IF;
...
```